# Can't understand & ~ syntaxes in a bitwise operator in Stringbuilder internal method

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, stringbuilder

From the description of StringBuilder class:

```
private int GetReplaceBufferCapacity(int requiredCapacity)
    {
        // This function assumes that required capacity will be less
        // than the max capacity of the StringBuilder
        Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(requiredCapacity <= m_MaxCapacity);

        int newCapacity = Capacity;
        // Round the current capacity to the nearest multiple of 2
        // that is larger than the required capacity.
        if (newCapacity < requiredCapacity)
        {
            newCapacity = (requiredCapacity + 1) & ~1;
        }
        return newCapacity;
    }
```

What does exactly mean by `& ~1`?

**Update 15 March 2023**

For all new users who come across this post - please check this guide on Microsoft site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators

Comment: What language is this? Because it's definitely not C. C# perhaps?

Comment: `& ~1` is bitwise AND and bitwise NOT. `~1` is a bit mask with all bits on except the last bit. So this adds 1 to `requredCapacity`, then sets the low-order by to 0.

Comment: Is this maybe Java? If so, please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: The line in question has the same meaning in most languages, so it doesn't really matter which language it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~` is the unary bitwise-invert operator, so `1`, which has the low bit set and all other bits unset, becomes a value with the low bit unset, and all other bits set. `&`, the bitwise-and operator, means to keep only the bits set in both operands (this operation is often referred to as "masking"). So `& ~1` unsets the low bit of the other operand, keeping the rest.

Since the code already added `1`, if `requiredCapacity` was originally even, then adding `1` sets the low bit, and the masking removes it again. If `requiredCapacity` was originally odd, the increment moves it up to the next even number, and the masking does nothing.

In short, it does exactly what the comment says:

```
    // Round the current capacity to the nearest multiple of 2
    // that is larger than the required capacity.
```

Comment: So, if I got it right, lets say 6 + 1 = 7, which is 111, then 7 & ~1 means the last 1 in 111 going to be inverted from 1 to 0 and we get 110 which is 6. Is this correct?

Comment: @HumbleNewbie: Almost. `7 & ~1` is *masking off* the final `1`, not inverting it. Inverting would turn `0` to `1`, and `1` to `0`, masking it off means it's a `0` regardless of what it used to be. So `5 + 1 = 6 (110)` would stay `110` (6), and `6 + 1 = 7 (111)` is masked to `110` (6).

Comment: Thank you very much! Being not a native speaker such example helps a lot!

Comment: I suppose I would have preferred `newCapacity = requiredCapacity + (requiredCapacity % 2 == 1 ? 1 : 0);` as it would have been more readable for me, but it's probably because I'm not used to seeing `~1` in code.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Yeah, there's a lot of ways to do it. `requiredCapacity + (requiredCapacity & 1)`, or `requiredCapacity + requiredCapacity % 2` would both do the trick as well (the original code doesn't strictly need parens either; bitwise operators are lower precedence than PEMDAS operators in all languages I know of, so `requiredCapacity + 1 & ~1` would be fine). The advantage to the chosen approach is not typing the same variable name twice (and therefore, for a non-optimizing compiler, it might avoid loading it twice from memory; optimizing compilers should be able to convert as needed).

Comment: @Enigmativity: Masking is a fairly common technique for lower level code though, so it's worth learning, even if it wasn't strictly needed here.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - Totally agree.